# Putty Swiss keyboard mapping

Tags: putty

I am using a QWERTZ swiss keyboard on my laptop with the windows OS and am using Putty and Xming to connect to an Ubuntu server. I seem to have a lot of problem with the keyboard mapping and couldnt find an option anywhere to set the keyboard layout. Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: no one has a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setxkbmap` command to set your desired keyboard layout like following:

```
setxkbmap us
```

for more information you can take a look at [this link](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/setxkbmap.1.xhtml)